# Ruby on Rails association errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, relational-database

Im creating a many to many association rails project, and im getting the following errors when i run new.html.erb:

```
Table 'purchase_form_rails.account_numbers_pi_names' doesn't exist

undefined local variable or method `account_numbers' for #<#<Class:0x2a979ef4>:0x2a978770>

Extracted source (around line #34):
```

(It should be looking in the database purchase_form_rails, and the table account_numbers (the in between table joining pi_names and account_numbers is pi_names_account_numbers)

Heres my new.html.erb:

```
  <div class="field">

        <% for account_number in @account_numbers %>
           <input type="checkbox"
                id="<%=account_number.id%>"
                name="account_numbers_ids[]"
                value="<%=account_number.id %>"
                <%if @pi_name.account_numbers.include? tag%>checked="checked"<%end%>
         > <%=account_numbers.account_number%>
        <% end %>

  </div>
```

Let me know if you need any more info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are defining a has_many:thorough then rails expects join table name should be alphabetically sorted like account_numbers_pi_names( This should be the join table name not pi_names_account_numbers) .

Comment: Oh interesting never knew that. Ok so that worked. But now i got a new error `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) Extracted source (around line #33): `

Comment: Can you tell me what are you trying to acheive? did you look into fields_for method

Comment: I am brand new to Rails. Do you of any good guides/tutorials that explain basically how to get certain information from the database into the view / many to many associations?

Comment: You can go thorough rails casts on nested forms and complex forms http://railscasts.com/

Answer (score 1):

for many to many associations, rails convention expects the join/link table to be in alpha order, you said

> the in between table joining pi_names and account_numbers is pi_names_account_numbers

but the error says

> account_numbers_pi_names' doesn't exist

change the table name from 'pi_names_account_numbers' to 'account_numbers_pi_names' should fix the issue